# Justify html text with Chinese/Japanese characters

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

i'm developing an ipad ebook reader, and the css code below works for iOS5 , but not working for iOS 4.3.

```
text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-ideograph;
```

[image: SCREENSHOT]

ps: my html file contains Chinese/Japanese characters.
sorry for my English.

Comment: if it's not supported , how can i do this? is there any other way?

Comment: If you **must** use text-align:justify I have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

Try out CSS3 solution.

The CSS3 modules currently in development will introduce a large number of properties designed to support non-Latin text, from vertical script support to kashida justification, from ruby positioning to list numbering. This article will give you a glimpse of some of the properties that lie in store, and discuss how you can help to make these improvements a reality.

Kindly refer to [**link**](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/css3-text/) for more details!